# Hyperlink navigation via Ctrl+click in Eclipse Oxygen does not work

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt, code-navigation

After upgrading from Eclipse Neon to Oxygen I noticed that I can no longer navigate around the code by clicking on definitions while holding the **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>** key down. The indexer itself works fine, and I can still jump around by pressing **<kbd>F3</kbd>** or using the context menu.

I am using Eclipse CDT with C++.

The following screenshot proves that the feature is enabled:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it only broken when editing one language(family)? Is there anything in the error log when it fails to respond?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably running into [bug 517610](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517610). Note the following workaround from the bug:

> To work around the problem, you can disable the Change Log hyperlink
>   by going to Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors >
>   Hyperlinking, then untick "Changelog Detector".

The bug fix is scheduled for Oxygen.1, which will be released on September 27th 2017. Alternatively, you can update to the latest development build (6.1.0) of Linux Tools (which is the component that contained the bug) via the update site `http://download.eclipse.org/linuxtools/update/`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the first solution, increase the "Maximum number of tokens per translation unit" in your Eclipse.

[image]