# Key bindings with Ctrl key not working in Eclispse CDT unless I disable welcome screen

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, key-bindings, eclipse-oxygen

I have recently installed eclipse CDT on Linux.

> Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
>
> Build id: 20171218-0600

All the bindings like

> Ctrl + D
>
> Ctrl + Space

work fine after any project creation but when I restart eclipse they stop responding. I tried solution posted at [this page answered by howlger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292251/hyperlink-navigation-via-ctrlclick-in-eclipse-oxygen-does-not-work) which didn't work for me and upon some Googling I found a work around at [eclipse bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=426557) which resolved the issue by just disabling the welcome page.

But I would like to know the exact problem here, whether it is a focused view issue or something else. By the way, I would actually like to have the welcome screen during the launch.

Comment: I think it's unlikely people on StackOverflow will have more information about this problem than is available in the bug report.

Comment: I would like to know how a simple welcome screen can effect the key bindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in latest installer.